# Zend Optimizer not compatible with PHP+APC+Drupal. Can I disable it for Drupal-run domains?

Tags: php, php5, apache-2.2, drupal, zend

I use the following set up:

- PHP Version 5.2.17
- Apache/2
- Zend Optimizer v3.3.3
- Drupal 7.8

As far as I read other articles and questions, Zend Optimizer doesn't do any good neither for PHP5 nor for D7.

I would like to use APC as PHP cache but APC is not compatible with Zend Optimizer.

Can I disable Zend Optimizer for selected subdomains ?

---

### Example:

- ***sub1.example.com*** redirects to an app that requires Zend Optimizer
- ***sub2.example.com*** redirects to a Drupal app that doesn't require Zend
  Optimizer (I would like to disable Zend Optimizer for this subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhosting talk seems to think you may be able to use the php_value flag in your .htaccess (or VirtualHost def) in order to selectivly disable it in certain hosts:

```
php_value zend_optimizer.optimization_level = 0
```

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=947413

Comment: Thank you, I tried this on one subdomain and included php_value in my .htaccess but it didn't help disable Zend Optimizer I am afraid.

Comment: I checked this again and used this php_value in php.ini instead of .htaccess then after httpd -k restart it disabled all Zend Optimizer optimization passes but this was for the whole server not for one subdomain. I am looking further for a solution.

Comment: I've tried it again in my .htaccess but without success. What should be done in order to enable setting php_value in .htaccess ?

Comment: Instead of putting it in your .htaccess, try php_admin_value in your virtual host definition. Some settings are restricted to where they can be set from; the php/zend documentation leaves a bit to be desired on this front, unfortunately!